# Filling an object in a foreach - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I have real data, but in the example below I cannot get the object to fill with the data.

```
var dataset = {};
        $.each(data.body, function( index, value ) 
        {
            dataset[index] = {
                label: 'hell0',
                data: [0, 0, 200179, 280179, 33179, 220179, 220179, 210179, 200179, 280179, 33179, 220179],
                borderWidth: 2
            }

        });

         console.log(dataset);
```

Comment: Define cannot, does it error? Wrong format?

Comment: Totally empty object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simple `map` of `Array` (should work as long as `data.body` is not an empty array)

```
var dataset = data.body.map(function(item) {
  return {
    label: 'hell0',
    data: [0, 0, 200179, 280179, 33179, 220179, 220179, 210179, 200179, 280179, 33179, 220179],
    borderWidth: 2
  }
});
```